# Spring-data-rest 2.5.6 -> Setter no longer called

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-rest

When I upgrade from Spring Boot 1.4.1 to 1.4.3 Spring-data-rest is upgraded from 2.5.3 to 2.5.6.

After that a @OneToMany property in a SDR-managed Resource is no longer set via its setter (I assume now via direct field access).

What has to be done that the setter is called again? I already tried @JsonProperty/@JsonIgnore - with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a property access in entities.
Look example #2 in my repo: https://github.com/Cepr0/restdemo